# Erlang bitstring to integer conversion

Tags: erlang

I have an erlang bitstring based on the network representation of a MAC address, e.g. `<<255,0,0,0,0,1>>`, and would like to convert it to an integer. What is the most efficient way to go about this conversion?

Thanks,
Matt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read it out:

```
2> <<N:48/integer>> = <<255,0,0,0,0,1>>.
<<255,0,0,0,0,1>>
3> N.
280375465082881
```

Though it does not match the number you want. Perhaps due to some floating point rounding error?

Answer (score 15):

You can choose how much data you pack/match by using the `:Size` and `-unit:N` options:

```
1> <<X:6/integer-unit:8>> = <<255,0,0,0,0,1>>.
<<255,0,0,0,0,1>>
2> X.
280375465082881
```

Or more dynamically:

```
3> Bin = <<255,0,0,0,0,1>>.                 
<<255,0,0,0,0,1>>
4> Size = size(Bin). 
6
5> <<Int:(Size)/integer-unit:8>> = Bin.     
<<255,0,0,0,0,1>>
6> Int.
280375465082881
```

Using these variable sizes, you can unpack pretty much whatever you want.

Comment: Don't listen to this guy, he gives TERRIBLE ADVICE :P

Comment: Great answer, but I GIVE CRAP ANSWERS, who I can only presume is your mortal enemy, beat you to it by 1 minute.

Comment: gonna vote for this terrible advice just to even out the score

Comment: @IGIVETERRIBLEADVICE cool. can you help with universal way to parse big endian -> int, when big endian isn't deviable by 8.

Answer (score 1):

1> binary_to_list(<<255,0,0,0,0,1>>).

[255,0,0,0,0,1]

For example.

Comment: I think maybe I wasn't clear - I want to convert to a single 48 bit number, not a list of numbers. In the case above, I want the answer to be 280375481860097